# PHP string variable in MySQL Like query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

so I'm attempting to take in a PHP variable and do insert it into a simple sql query, but it's not working and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

NOTE: I know this code has security issues

staff_model.php file:

```
function getSearches($searchterm) {
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM people 
                WHERE name 
                LIKE '%{$searchterm}%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

My table has several columns but it has columns like id, name, subject, type. The way I get $searchterm is something like

```
var searchText = document.getElementById('custom-search-text').value;
```

in my javascript file and I'll pass it to users.php through

```
$.get(url+"/api/users/staff", {id: id, name: name, type: type, subject: subject, search: searchText})
```

Just to make sure everything else was working correctly, I hardcoded something for searchTerm (so something like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'Matt'"`) and I did get the correct results.

Something else I tried was `$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE $searchTerm"` and this didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can get it to work with wildcards?

Comment: try this: - $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '$searchTerm' "

Comment: @AnkurTiwari results came back empty

Comment: and what will be result with just "SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 10" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this
 $sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM people 
         WHERE name 
         LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";

using . as concatenating operator

Comment: I tried this query and it still came back with nothing. Is it possible that something else is wrong somewhere else?

Comment: I'm able to see the count. Here is my code
<?php
include("db.php");
    $sku = 'HTH001';
    $queryString = "SELECT sku from items where sku LIKE '%".$sku ."%'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$queryString);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
mysqli_close($db);
?>

Can you please share your entire code?

Comment: Nevermind, I had another dumb issue somewhere else, but I wasn't seeing the error until I messed around with the code more

Answer (score 0):

How about "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";